# Error occur when trying to send urdu text through GSM

Tags: python, python-2.7, sms, gsm, unicode-string

I am a beginner in python and GSM. I have made a system using GSM & Python that receives user text messages and respond to their queries through SMS. When I send english text it is working fine, but when I try to send urdu text through GSM in it shows error of unicode characters. and user is receiving either empty message or some garbage.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] that illustrates your problem. We can't debug code that we can't see.

Comment: In general text mode (AT+CMGF and so on) does not support Unicode (which you need) so you need to communicate with the modem in PDU (binary) mode instead.  Some hardware may offer the ability to send Unicode in text mode using escapes, to see if thats the case with your device research the AT+CSCS command.

Comment: Corrected spelling, grammar

Comment: I am using python utility for connecting to GSM device and sending and receiving messages through it. (https://github.com/adammck/pygsm) whenever i try to send text in Urdu language it juts send Error Response to me.